# Is it safe to save .xlsx or pdf uploads?

Tags: mysql, node.js, security

I have a webpage that accepts user uploads in xlsx and pdf format, and then saves them in an "uploads" folder. Im wondering if there might be any security issues with the uploads content (viruses, hacks, etc) that might compromise my servers safety, and if there are, how can i address the issue.

Im working with mysql and nodejs.

Thank you

Comment: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/File_Upload_Cheat_Sheet.html

Comment: To compromise your server the code in uploaded file must be executed. If you do not execute it then there is no any problem.

Comment: If you do execute it, excel is more dangerous for having the ability to execute scripts.

Comment: Yes, i need to read the excel to retrieve the information. I guess it can be dangerous then, how can i protect my server against it?

Comment: pdf contents that render can do all kinds of things like calling remote url's, and loading fonts, displaying rich media content and a bunch of things, excel files that allow macros allow people to run custom code. Security is about reducing your liability, removing liability would be stopping people from doing anything..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check your content security policy to be sure, you likely need moderation/abuse, security controls on files, and you also need to take care how users upload files. This question could be called very broad.

That said there are a great number of problems that come with hosting user supplied files. You likely should have a security audit, make sure you can trace who is uploading, and understand the unit economics of allowing people to post things server side.

Since the question is broad, its hard to give a better answer..